# How can I redirect to another controller?

Tags: php, redirect, zend-framework2

I have two controller, `IndexController.php` and `LoginController.php`. I want to go to `IndexController.php` after a successful login. I have:

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute(NULL , array( 
    'controller' => 'login',  
    'action' => 'home'
);
```

It works well, but when I write:

```
'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index'
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: You should specify route name (instead of NULL value).

Answer (score 2):

In yours `module.config.php` you must create a route for each controller. For example, if the route of the first controller is `myroute1` and the route of the second controller is `myroute2`, we will have :

To access the first controller :

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('myroute1', [
    'controller' => 'login', 
    'action' => 'home'
]);
```

To access the second controller :

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('myroute2', [
    'controller' => 'index', 
    'action' => 'index'
]);
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I post my module.config.php and LoginController.php below: please help me sir.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `forward` method of controller to dispatch other action of other controller without redirect:

```
return $this->forward()->dispatch('/MyModule/Controller/MyController', ['action' => 'index']);
```